# Using Streams filter Map based on a list of keys

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a particular problem and was wondering whether the Java 8 Streams API could solve it.  I know that this can be done outside of using Streams API but I don't want to add all the boilerplate code associated with trying to achieve that, if it can be done using Streams. I have a map

```
Map<String, String> greetings = new HashMap<>();
greetings.put("abc", "Hello");
greetings.put("def", "Goodbye");
greetings.put("ghi", "Ciao");
greetings.put("xyz", "Bonsoir");
```

and a list of keys:

```
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("def", "zxy");
```

and using the above with Streams API, is it possible to filter that down to:

```
Map<String, String> filteredGreetings = new HashMap<>();
filteredGreetings.put("def", "Goodbye");
filteredGreetings.put("xyz", "Bonsoir");
```

Hopefully this makes sense what I am trying to achieve.

So far I have got this to work only when specifying the exact key which to filter the map's keySet on, but then this would only return a single entry set. I am interested in a completely filtered down map and I am struggling to achieve that.

Comment: Is it just a coincidental, typo or a requirement, I get to notice the key `"zxy"` and the result still `put("xyz", "Bonsoir")`?

Comment: Yep, that’s a typo. Apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map<String, String> result = keys.stream()
        .filter(greetings::containsKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), greetings::get));
```

Or the other way round:

```
Map<String, String> result = greetings.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> keys.contains(e.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

For the second approach I would recommend using a [`Set<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for a larger list of `keys` because it has a *O(1)* time complexity for `.contains()` because it does not contain any duplicates:

```
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("def", "zxy"));
```

Comment: For a list of two elements, the time complexity really doesn’t matter. In fact, the overhead of hashing will be higher than the linear lookup.

Comment: @Holger Yes that's true. Just want to add that information for general.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp spot-on - thanks a lot! I wasn't aware of "identity" either. I need to read up a bit more on this.

Comment: @RichardC `Function.identity()` is a synonym for `i -> i`.

Answer (score 4):

If the input and the expected output in the question [is not a typo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602270/using-streams-filter-map-based-on-a-list-of-keys#comment99783437_56602270), you can also retain the keys of the input map as:

```
Map<String, String> futureGreetings = new HashMap<>(greetings);
futureGreetings.keySet().retainAll(keys);
```

Comment: Of course, this doesn't use streams, but one can compare the complexity and readability for both the solutions before opting.

Comment: That's the best and most simple solution. Much better than mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
filteredGreetings= keys.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),key->greetings.get(key)));
```

or even for absent key you can use `getOrDefault()` method.

```
... .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),key->greetings.getOrDefault(key,"")));
```

Comment: Because that I added second approach. Though I think he did not mean the keys were absent